# Method causes OutOfMemory error

Tags: object, recursion, unity-game-engine

If a GameObject in my game has a special ability it triggers it, but I want all the special GameObjects that this GameObject affects to also trigger their abilities, for example if a bomb hits some objects, if these objects are also bombs, trigger them too. I though this would be easy by calling the method that handles all the special abilities recursively, but in programming not many things are as easy as you thought at the beginning. Basically what happened is a chain reaction of bullcrap that caused Unity to show an OurOfMemory error. Also makes my PC freeze completely while politely turning all the screens off.

The question is, how can I make it so it triggers all the affected cubes' special abilities, without everything going nuts?

Code:

```
     //Triggers the cube's special ability, if it has any
    private void TriggerSpecialCubeAbility(GameObject specialCube) {
        switch (specialCube.tag) {

            //Destroy all cubes in a radius from the special cube
            case "Bomb":
                TriggerBombAbility(specialCube);
                break;

            //Destroy all cubes of the same color as the special cube
            case "Lighting":
                TriggerLightingAbility(specialCube);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void TriggerBombAbility(GameObject specialCube) {
        var nearbyColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(specialCube.transform.position, explosionRadius);
        Instantiate(particles[0], specialCube.transform.position, specialCube.transform.rotation);
        Instantiate(particles[1], specialCube.transform.position, specialCube.transform.rotation);

        foreach (var collider in nearbyColliders) {
            if (collider.tag == "Indestructible")
                return;

            var affectedCube = collider.gameObject;
            TriggerSpecialCubeAbility(affectedCube);
            Destroy(affectedCube);
        }

        destroySelectedCubes = true;
        //          Physics2D.gravity *= -1;
        //          Physics.gravity *= -1;
    }
```

Comment: If two bomb cubes are nearby, won't this end up with a stack overflow? The first triggers the second, the second triggers the first again, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is an endless loop.
Assume bomb A being near bomb B.

1. bomb A explodes.
2. bomb A explosion triggers bomb B.
3. bomb B explodes
4. bomb B explosion triggers bomb A.
5. go back to 1

You can simply resolve this by remembering if an object has already been triggered, and then preventing any further triggering.

```
bool thisObjectHasBeenTriggered = false;

//Triggers the cube's special ability, if it has any, AND HAS NOT BEEN TRIGGERED YET
private void TriggerSpecialCubeAbility(GameObject specialCube)
{
    if (thisObjectHasBeenTriggered)
        return;
    thisObjectHasBeenTriggered = true;

    switch (specialCube.tag)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```